# How to Contract a Rank 2 Tensor with a Rank 1 Tensor

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, tensor

I have a rank 2 tensor obtained by acting with the grad operator twice successively on a function `[Psi]`, so let's call this tensor `[Psi]2`. I then simply want to contract it over its two indices with a vector f such that I obtain a new vector, but cannot get it to work for some reason, so not sure if I am doing the wrong syntax.

I've tried to change a code slightly which works when contracting a rank 2 tensor with another rank 2 tensor to get a scalar.

This is the code I am trying:

`Sum[f[[i]]*[Psi]2[[i, j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]`

Compare this with the code I have written which enables me to contract a rank 2 tensor with another rank 2 tensor to get a scalar

`Gddrr = Sum[GG[[i, j]]*rr[[i, j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];`

where `GG` and `rr` are both rank 2.  However, although I am expecting to obtain a vector from this contraction, I am getting a scalar instead.

[Psi] = R/(8*pi)

f = {f1, f2, f3}

Comment: I don't know a lot of Mathematica, but presumably `Sum` will always give you a scalar. You need a way of splitting up the sum into the different vector/tensor components, like assigning the partial sums to that index. @Tom

Comment: Yes, so it's like if I have f_i and g_ij, I just need to sum over the first index of the rank 2 tensor somehow but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of Psi and f? Sounds like you need to use a [Dot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) product?

Comment: I've added the examples as requested, bear in mind f is a general vector, then psi is a scalar which becomes a rank 2 tensor after I act on it twice with the grad operator.

Comment: What's the term `[Psi]2` supposed to be ?  What kind of *Mathematica* entity or thing is it ?.  Yes, I see you want to use it as the name of a tensor, but *Mathematica* has it's own ideas about names and other forms.  If I try to evaluate your first expression (ie `Sum[f[[i]]*[Psi]2...`) *Mathematica* raises an error.

Comment: You see where I have defined Psi my post to be R/(8*pi), I act on that once with grad to get something I call [Psi]1, then act on [Psi]1 with grad to get something I call [Psi]2.

Comment: What do you mean by 'act on that once with grad'? What is R?